# reading from file using fscanf and saving into a array of struct c language

Tags: c, arrays, struct

I am trying to read from a file and save the data into an array of struct. However I am at loss on how do I go about it.

The struct is like this

```
struct Student students {
    int stuid;
    char name[21];
    double grade;
}
```

The text file is something like this

```
1,76.50,Joe Smith
2,66.77,John Campbell
3,88.99,Jane Common
```

The code I tried ended up something like this

```
//declaring the struct
struct Student test[3];

int loadgrade(struct Student* student, FILE* file) {
    while (fscanf(file, "%d,%lf,%21[^\n]", &student.stuid, &student.grade, &student.name) == 3)
```

I am not sure how I would save the data into the array, as the way I have it will only save to the first element and never go on. Do I loop inside the while statement of reading the file?
Do I make another struct or temp variable to read the file and then loop it to transfer it? I am at a loss on this and would appreciate any kind of enlightenment.

Answer (score 2):

```
int loadgrade(struct Student* student, FILE* file) {
    int i = 0;
    while (fscanf(file, "%d,%lf,%20[^\n]", &student->stuid, &student->grade, student->name) == 3){
        ++student;
        ++i;
    }
    return i;
}
```

call `int n = loadgrade(test, fp);`

Answer (score 1):

So this is somewhat confusing because `student` is a pointer, but the way to do this is as such

```
fscanf(file, "%d,%lf,%20[^\n]", &(student->stuid), &(student->grade), student->name);
```

Now if you want to fill the array `test`, you can do this

```
for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
   fscanf(file, "%d,%lf,%20[^\n]", &(test[i]->stuid), &(test[i]->grade), test[i]->name);
```

Having said that, you need to declare `test` like this `struct Student * test[3]`.

Comment: Let me help you now that you helped me: you should use %20 not %21 or the limit is useless (null terminator string).

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre That is true. I wasn't thinking of the null terminator in specifying.

Comment: Just notice that you can use, but don't need parens in `&student->stuid`.

Comment: On the other hand, if you change `test` to an array of pointers, you now need to allocate memory. So it's best to keep it as it is and use `&test[i].stuid`.

Comment: I tried following your answer, but on my end it ends up only adding the last line on the file 3 times, rather than all 3 lines. Do I put the for loop inside the while fscanf?